# Why does rotation not rotate in center? (Android)

Tags: java, android, rotation

I'm still kind of new to android and I'm trying to rotate a layout around it's deadcenter pivot point. I've made sure the layout has the same height and width but I simply cannot understand that once I rotate, some sort of padding is added, thus the rotation moved the layout somehow.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are some screens:
[image: default layout]
[image: rotated with movement]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/capture_menu_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:background="@color/red">

            <com.mycomp.custom.Fontastic
            android:id="@+id/menu_icon_icon"
            android:text="@string/ft_burger_menu_outlined"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my Activity rotation part:

```
private void rotateView(int oldOrientation, int orientation, View... views) {
    /*
     * If the current orientation is Inverted portrait, and the user changes to inverted
     * landscape, (or vice versa) we have to make sure the animation rotates the right way
     * otherwise the animation rotates 270 degrees to the new position, instead of only
     * having to rotate 90 degrees.
     */

    // PortraitInverted --> LandscapeInverted
    if (oldOrientation == 180 && orientation == -90) oldOrientation = -180;
        // LandscapeInverted --> PortraitInverted
    else if (oldOrientation == -90 && orientation == 180) orientation = -180;

    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(oldOrientation, orientation,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setDuration(400);

    for (View v : views){
        v.clearAnimation();
        v.setAnimation(rotate);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Things I've tried:

- Removing any margin/padding
- Setting the rotation to 0.25f
- Setting the fontastic or relativelayout to a fixed equal width and height

The activity is locked in portrait mode.

Comment: do you need to use animation?

Comment: I'd prefer it yes, because it's a visible item and it'll look better if the transition was smooth. If there are other ways that give an animation effect, then that's okay too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem, running setAnimation in the post closure fixed a problem like this for me.